# how to match longest matching string

Tags: r

I have string and character vector. I would like to find all strings in character vector matching as much as possible characters from beging of string.
For example:

```
s <- "abs"
vc <- c("ab","bb","abc","acbd","dert")

result <- c("ab","abc")
```

String s should be matched exactly up to first K characters. I want match for as much as possible (max K<=length(s)).
Here there is no match for "abs" (grep("abs",vc)), but for "ab" there are two matches (result <-grep("ab",vc)).

Comment: s is string, vc is character vector, result is expected result for this example data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another interpretation:

```
s <- "abs"
# Updated vc
vc <- c("ab","bb","abc","acbd","dert","abwabsabs")

st <- strsplit(s, "")[[1]]
mtc <- sapply(strsplit(substr(vc, 1, nchar(s)), ""), 
              function(i) {
                m <- i == st[1:length(i)]
                sum(m * cumsum(m))})

vc[mtc == max(mtc)]
#[1] "ab"        "abc"       "abwabsabs"

# Another vector vc
vc <- c("ab","bb","abc","acbd","dert","absq","abab")
....
vc[mtc == max(mtc)]
#[1] "absq"
```

Since we are considering only beginnings of strings, in the first case the longest match was `"ab"`, even though there is `"abwabsabs"` which has `"abs"`.

**Edit:** Here is a "single pattern" solution, possibly it could be more concise, but here we go...

```
vc <- c("ab","bb","abc","acbd","dert","abwabsabs")
(auxOne <- sapply((nchar(s)-1):1, function(i) substr(s, 1, i)))
#[1] "ab"   "a"
(auxTwo <- sapply(nchar(s):2, function(i) substring(s, i)))
#[1] "s" "bs" 
l <- attr(regexpr(
  paste0("^((",s,")|",paste0("(",auxOne,"(?!",auxTwo,"))",collapse="|"),")"),
  vc, perl = TRUE), "match.length")
vc[l == max(l)]
#[1] "ab"        "abc"       "abwabsabs"
```

Comment: @WojciechSobala, just added a regex solution.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. I think that pattern string could be simplified to gsub("(.)","\\1?",s).

Comment: @WojciechSobala, it does not seem so, try `vc <- "bs"`, your pattern finds a match of length 2, while it should be 0 as I understand. `a?b?s?` fits for `as`, `bs` too.

Comment: For my data it works but you are right in general case. I think that paste0(gsub("(.)","(\\1",s), gsub(".","?)",s)) should be better.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that uses `grep` and checks to see if a given string `s` matches the beginning of any string in `vc`, recursively removing a character from the end of `s`:

```
myfun <- function(s, vc) {
  notDone <- TRUE
  maxChar <- max(nchar(vc))  # EDIT: these two lines truncate s to
  s <- substr(s, 1, maxChar) # the maximum number of chars in vc
  subN <- nchar(s)
  while(notDone & subN > 0){
    ss <- substr(s, 1, subN)
    ans <- grep(sprintf("^%s", ss), vc, val = TRUE)
    if(length(ans)) {
      notDone <- FALSE
    } else {
      subN <- subN - 1
    }
  }
  return(ans)
}

s <- "abs"
# Updated vc from @Julius's answer
vc <- c("ab","bb","abc","acbd","dert","absq","abab")

> myfun(s, vc)
[1] "absq"

# And there's no infinite recursion if there's no match
> myfun("q", "a")
character(0)
```

Comment: Hm, I suppose truncating `s` to the max `nchar` in `vc` would make sense, too.

Comment: Both s and vc can be truncated to pmin(length(s), max(vc)).

Comment: +1 your solution is correct but I wonder if it is possible to solve this problem using regular expression.

Comment: @WojciechSobala, My gut feeling tells me there's no gain in truncating `vc`, but truncating `s` would speed up this function if `s` is much longer than `max(char(vc))` (see edits above). `grep` does use regular expressions!

Comment: in my dataset I have to compare each of ~60 strings with vector of length ~500, so speed is not an issue. Yes your function uses grep but I wonder if it is possible to write single pattern string.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note, long after the fact, that the [triebeard](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/triebeard/index.html) package now exists; it's very, very efficient and user-friendly for finding longest or partial matches.